# Firefox/Thunderbird "Personas" do not cover window decorations

Tags: compiz, firefox, window-decoration

Is there anyway to make Firefox Personas cover window decorations?  Chrome seems to be able to do this if you disable the GTK theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it doesn't mean to do this. Chrome uses a hard-coded window decoration for it-self which is not rational in GNU/Linux world

Comment: That's a shame, and pretty much validates my suspicions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple "un-decorate" right click to have the persona from top to bottom on my Firefox browser. This also had to be done with Chrome as well. I could not find a persona nor theme that would cover window decorations. Sorry Dean.